# Activity date on Task different when copied to parent Lead via trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am updating lead with task activity date using a trigger when ever i am creating a new task record on lead object, but there is miss match in date while it is updating on the lead

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of implicit conversion from the salesforce for user Defined timezone to the GMT. When you are creating the task it is creating the task as per user time zone but same date and when you copy it for the lead it will get converted to the GMT.

So its better take the GMT as standard convert it to user defined date and then save the lead record .

Hope this helps.

Comment: can i know how to convert it before updating the lead